# Tapping on TableViewCell to show UIPickerView

Tags: swift, uitableview, uikit, uipickerview

I have a custom TableViewCell and UIPickerView as an inputView to a cell's textview:

```
class PickerTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    let picker = UIPickerView()

    let pickerOptions: [String] = []

    lazy var pickerTextField: UITextFieldWithNoCursor = {
       let pickerTextField = UITextFieldWithNoCursor()
       pickerTextField.inputView = picker
       ...
       return pickerTextField
    }()


    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        containerStackView.addArrangedSubview(pickerTextField)
    }
}
```

The problem is with selecting the picker. It only works by tapping on the textview, but if I tap on some other part of the cell it will do nothing. Is there a way to show a pickerView by tapping on the whole cell and not only its textview?

Answer (score 0):

You can add tap gesture in your cell to do that

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
           super.awakeFromNib()

           let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapEdit))
           addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)


       }

       @objc func tapEdit() {

        pickerTextField.becomeFirstResponder()

       }
```